# How to remove the dictionary element from an array by its name value

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swift5

I have a list of Array for Name list & url
Want to remove from

```
    func getNameListData() -> [[String: Any]] {
        return [
            [
                "name”: “Jonny”,
                "imageName”: “url.png"
            ],
            [
                "name”: ”Mark”,
                "imageName”: “url.png”
            ],
            [
                "name": “Kiran”,
                "imageName": “url.png”
            ],
            [
                "name": “David”,
                "imageName": “url.png”
            ],
        ]
}
```

// Get Name List Array

```
  var nameList = self.getNameListData()
```

// remove Object at index Value
`nameList.remove(at: 0)`
// Remove element for specified element

How to remove element by name value ?

This is what I tried, its not working for me.

```
if let index = nameList.firstIndex(where: {$0 as? String == "Kiran" }) {
    nameList.remove(at: index)
    }
```

if there any way for removing an element from array of JSONDictionary i.e [[String:Any]]

It give following warning

**Cast from 'JSONDictionary' (aka 'Dictionary<String, Any>') to unrelated type 'String' always fails
Cast from 'JSONDictionary' (aka 'Dictionary<String, Any>') to unrelated type 'String' always fails**

Result count = 3.

Comment: Unrelated but why do you use unspecified `Any`? The dictionary is clearly `[String:String]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close -- right now, you're trying to caste the entire `[String:Any]` dictionary to `String`. Instead, you should be looking at just the "name" entry and casting it's value to `String` to compare to "Kiran".

```
if let index = nameList.firstIndex(where: {$0["name"] as? String  == "Kiran" }) {
    nameList.remove(at: index)
}
```